# ¿Por qué el Auth de Laravel 6 no me saca el uuid completo de un usuario logueado?

Tags: laravel

en un link de la barra de navegación quiero mandar el id del usuario al controlador, pero al poner el `Auth::user()->id` me doy cuenta que solo me ha sacado los 2 primeros dígitos del uuid que estoy usando.

Ya traté diferentes cosas pero sigue igual. ¿Alguna idea de como corregir esto?

Comment: Puedes colocar un ejemplo, porfavor

Comment: Tengo `{{ url('/estate/searchByAgent/' . Auth::user()->id) }}` en un enlace, el id es un uuid de MySQL así como "15a5422e-046b-11ea-8970-f0761cc086a3" pero el `Auth::user()->id` solo me regresa el 15 por ejemplo

Comment: Como generaste el UUID, podrias mostrar el codigo?, ya que laravel solo te genera un `int`-entero, como `ID` unico, tendrias que generar por algun tipo de codigo o libreria un `UUID` en laravel.

Comment: Lo acabo de solucionar, después de mucho tiempo volví a la pregunta y en el modelo User en `$cast` agregé `'id' => 'string'`